# How to deploy domain name from Sandbox to UAT/Production

Tags: community, salesforcedx, deployment, site.com, custom-domain

I have updated the domain name in the sandbox, now I have to deploy it to UAT and then the Production environment.

Is it possible to perform this via changeset/workbench or do I have to perform the domain name change manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you can do it. Unfortunately, you'll have to do in manually.

Plus, Have a look at further considerations: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_mgmt_sandbox_custom_domains_considerations.htm&type=5